# RoR: Get file (attachment) name/location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

In my app I want users to be able to associate a file(s) they have on their desktop/DropBox with a specific item, but I don't want/need them to be able to actually attach the file...I just want to get the file name and location and save that in my database.  Then when I display the item I'll hyperlink to the location captured.  Can someone point me to an example(s) of how to accomplish this?  I looked at the JQuery File Upload (http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) but as I mentioned don't actually need to upload the file...so this should be something super easy.

Thanks for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and get value of file input, but you'll fail.

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncFh3/1/).

All I'm getting is the fake path

```
C:\fakepath\134.png
```

And there's certainly no `C:\` drive on Mac OSX. :)

I guess, this is because of security restrictions. You shouldn't know (or care) about user's filesystem in a web app.

Comment: Thanks.  I still need to the full path...is there a way to get this?  I'm not uploading anything, but I still want the user to be able to click on the link and open the file on their computer. Think of it as not uploading a Word doc, but capturing the location of the Word doc on their PC, then when they click on the link within my app I want the Word doc to open.

Comment: @user464180: not with javascript. Maybe flash or AIR or java will be more useful here.